# Get result to temptable by execute OPENROWSET stored procedures with dynamic parameters in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012, I need result to temp-table by execute stored procedure with dynamic parameter values.

Below I show my code, while I execute code I get an error, so is this possible to get output with dynamic parameters while execute stored procedures in `openrowset` or something like this?

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT * INTO #TempStamp_Status       
             FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',
        ''Admin-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS'' ; ''sa'' ; ''123456''
        ''SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;exec 
RDS_DS.dbo.Qry_GetParticipationDetails ' + cast( @ResidentId AS 
NVARCHAR(10))   + ',''' +CAST(@StartDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) +''',''' 
+CAST(@EndDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) +''')''';
```

When I execute this SQL query, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;exec RDS_DS.dbo.Qry_GetParticipationDetails 52,'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing quotes. Could you try this?

```
SET @sql = N'SELECT * INTO #TempStamp_Status       
             FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',
        ''Admin-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS'' ; ''sa'' ; ''123456'',
        ''SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;exec 
RDS_DS.dbo.Qry_GetParticipationDetails ' + cast( @ResidentId AS 
NVARCHAR(10))   + ',''''' +CAST(@StartDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) +''''',''''' 
+CAST(@EndDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) +''''''')';
```

Comment: Hi, this answer execute successfull, but how can i get that temptable result, i tried select * from #TempStamp_Status,but i get"Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 23
Invalid object name '#TempStamp_Status'."

Comment: you can use a real table instead of temp like `SELECT * INTO TempStamp_Status` or you can use a global temp table like `##TempStamp_Status`

Comment: Thanks for help, your answer is working successfully